# Definition of a Multivariate Normal random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-statistical-analysis

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definitions),
$$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {X} \ \sim \ {\mathcal {N}}(\mathbf {\mu } ,{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}) \iff {\text{there exist }}\mathbf {\mu } \in \mathbb {R} ^{k},{\boldsymbol {A}}\in \mathbb {R} ^{k\times \ell }{\text{ such that }}\mathbf {X} ={\boldsymbol {A}}\mathbf {Z} +\mathbf {\mu } {\text{ for }}Z_{n}\sim \ {\mathcal {N}}(0,1),{\text{ i.i.d.}}}
$$
For a non-degenerate distribution, does $k$ always have to be equal to $l$?
Some texts like [this](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/multivariate-normal-distribution) and [this](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ewahed/teaching/2083/fall09/Lecture309.pdf) use $k = l$ directly in the definition itself, but I can't see why it's necessary

Answer (score 1):

If we want $\mathbf{X}$ to be non-degenerate, we should check whether the rank of the $k\times k$ matrix $Cov(\mathbf{X})=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\top}$ is $k$.

Since $rank(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\top})=rank(\mathbf{A})\le \min (k,l)$, $\mathbf{X}$ must be degenerate when $k>l$.

We can find an example to show $\mathbf{X}$ could be non-degenerate when $k<l$: just take $k=1$, $l=2$ and $\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! so $k= l$ is not necessary for anything?

Comment: I think so. I guess we just need $k\le l$. This could be explained by the intuition that we cannot create some non-degenerate $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ out of just $l$ i.i.d. $Z_n$ when $k>l$, since every component of $\mathbf{X}$ is a linear combination of $Z_1,\dots,Z_l$. However, we are happy with $k\le l$ because we just take what we need to compose $\mathbf{X}$ and it doesn't matter if we leave some $Z_n$ unused. From this perspective, the restriction $k=l$ seems unnecessary to me.